# Does html5 gelocation method position.address.city only work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, geolocation

Does the city method only work in Firefox? for example if I wanted to print the city of the user:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
      document.write(location.address.city);
    });
  }
```

If this is true, what's the best way to find a users city? Take the lat and long and plug it into google's location api?

Comment: The address property definitely isn't part of the current W3C Geolocation API spec (though civic address is under discussion for the second version), so I suspect it isn't supported by the other browsers. (I haven't checked personally though; I hadn't realized FF had this functionality either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the location.address.city only works in Firefox. I just confirmed that neither Safari or Chrome support the address property - both return 'undefined'.

You suggestion to retrieve the user's city by plugging lat/long into [Google's Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) should be a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
geocoder.geocode({location:latlng},function(result){
                    document.write(resul.address_components.long_name)
});
```

For more information please check out [the reference at google code](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderAddressComponent).

Answer (score -3):

no, it works in [all major browsers](http://html5demos.com/).

Look [here](http://html5demos.com/geo#view-source) for an example, which does seem to do what you suggested

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
```

also, a simple google search would've given you the same info in ~15 secs :)

Comment: I am asking specifically about the location.address.city method. It can be found in the mozilla documentation under nsIDOMGeoPositionAddress. Is the address interface only available in firefox?